# Check if part of a multi-dimensional list is in a seperate muti-dimensional list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array, syntax

Here is some example code.

```
list1 = [['one','a'],['two','a'],['three','a'],['four','a']]
list2 = [['three','b'],['four','a'],['five','b']]

for l in list1:
    if l not in list2:
        print(l[0])
```

and the output from this code.

```
one
two
three
```

because *['four','a']* does indeed appear in both lists.

What I am trying to do is check if just the first item of each entry within the first list appears in the second list, I have tried variations of the following

```
list1 = [['one','a'],['two','a'],['three','a'],['four','a']]
list2 = [['three','b'],['four','a'],['five','b']]

for l in list1:
    if l[0] not in list2:
        print(l[0])
```

however, that code returns

```
one
two
three
four
```

though both 'three' and 'four' do appear in the second list.

I have used different methods before now to find the values that appear in only one of a pair of lists, then used that to make a master list that contains all possible values with no duplicates and I believe the same should be possible using this method but the syntax is a mystery to me. Where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `not any()` and then you check specific requirements in the comprehension:

```
list1 = [['one','a'],['two','a'],['three','a'],['four','a']]
list2 = [['three','b'],['four','a'],['five','b']]

for l in list1:
    if not any(l[0] == l2[0] for l2 in list2):
        print(l[0])

# one
# two
```

You could also use sets if order doesn't matter:

```
list1 = [['one','a'],['two','a'],['three','a'],['four','a']]
list2 = [['three','b'],['four','a'],['five','b']]

set(l[0] for l in list1) - set(l2[0] for l2 in list2)
# {'one', 'two'}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `set operations`

```
list1 = [['one','a'],['two','a'],['three','a'],['four','a']]
list2 = [['three','b'],['four','a'],['five','b']]

result = set(i[0] for i in list1) - set(i[0] for i in list2)

print(result)

# output {'one', 'two'}
```